# nodejs get find results in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get the result of query but i get the same info in all vars: db, collection and res:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var mongoserver = new mongodb.Server("localhost", 27017);
var instance = new mongodb.Db("test", mongoserver);

instance.open(function(err, db)
{
  console.log('db:');
  console.log(db);
  db.collection('kurtsoa', function(err, collection)
  {
    console.log('collection:');
    console.log(collection);
    collection.find({}, function(err, res)
    {
      console.log('res:');
      console.log(res);
    });
  });
});
```

how i can get the result of "find"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`.find()`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find) will return a [Cursor](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/cursor.js) object for you to work with. If all you are interested in is getting all the results in an array you can do:

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
});
```

But you can also iterate the cursor too:

```
collection.find().each(function(err, doc) {
    //called once for each doc returned
});
```

Comment: Its a better answer and explanation as well .

Comment: a note for iterating the cursor; The 'doc' will be set to null once it finishes iterating all items. So you have to check before processing.

Comment: In the first snippet, why does `console.log(typeof(docs))` return `object`?   `toArray()` suggests it should return an array...so `docs.each()` within the *first* snippet doesn't work, but `console.log(docs.length)` does return the number of documents.  Also, I notice in the second snippet, `console.log(doc)` will return null once all documents have been iterated.  Why does it do that?

Comment: To answer your first question, `typeof([]) === 'object'`. To your second, the answer is just "that is how a Cusor works in this API".

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
 collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs){
                console.log(docs);
    )};
```